# Is it safe to modify product name attribute character limit

Tags: attributes, mysql

I'm reaching a character limit issue with the product name attribute which is in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, with a limit of 255 characters.

Is it safe for me to simply modify this using phpMyAdmin and modify this length to 500:

```
ALTER TABLE  `catalog_product_entity_varchar` CHANGE  `value`  `value` VARCHAR( 500 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'Value'
```

Could this cause detrimental effects other than increasing the table size?
I've run the query on a staging environment and am now able to bypass the 255 character limit, I'm just checking to see if anyone can think of something I am missing or should be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one official answer to this :

- No, don't ever modify the Magento Core code or db

*however* - If it works and you have tested it thoroughly it is a valid workaround to your problem.

I can only think of instances (like yours) where exceeding the character limit would cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , there is no issue if you alter character limit.

For one of my project I've alter character limit value, Site is live and found no problem with this.